# Corollary to Maschke's Theorem.

Tags: representation-theory, group-rings

If in Maschke's Theorem, for group ring KG where K is any field s.t. char $K \nmid |G|$, I take G to be finite , then I know Maschke implies that KG will be semisimple so it is isomorphic to a direct sum of Matrices over division rings, but how does adding that G is also abelian implies that KG will be direct sum of fields?

Comment: More general question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/661519/15416

Comment: $G$ is abelian iff $K[G]$ is commutative. A matrix algebra is commutative iff it's a $1 \times 1$ matrix algebra, and a division ring is commutative iff it's a field.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: That should be an answer.